# How to set permissions for RabbitMQ directory to create new files?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, rabbitmq, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server

I would like to move the RABBITMQ_BASE files to "/opt/rabbitmq"

I've attempted the following, but it appears that I'm making a mistake somewhere:

```
(while logged in as root)
mkdir -p /opt/rabbitmq
sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /opt/rabbitmq
sudo chmod 766 -R /opt/rabbitmq
```

here is the contents of my rabbitmq-env.conf

```
RABBITMQ_BASE=/opt/rabbitmq
export RABBITMQ_NODENAME=rabbit@localhost
export RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
export ERL_EPMD_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
export RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE=/opt/rabbitmq/MNESIA
```

I've checked the logs in /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_log:

```
BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
   {error,{cannot_create_mnesia_dir,"/opt/rabbitmq/MNESIA/rabbit@localhost/",
                                    eacces}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_mnesia,ensure_mnesia_dir,0,
                   [{file,"src/rabbit_mnesia.erl"},{line,505}]},
    {rabbit_node_monitor,prepare_cluster_status_files,0,
                         [{file,"src/rabbit_node_monitor.erl"},{line,101}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-0-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,270}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,403}]},
    {init,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]}]

{"init terminating in do_boot",{error,{cannot_create_mnesia_dir,"/opt/rabbitmq/MNESIA/rabbit@localhost/",eacces}}}
```

The "/opt" directory is owned by root, but the permissions for the other directories are as follows:

```
ubuntu root@/opt $ ls -lah
total 48K
drwx------ 10      700 root     4.0K Jul 14 12:42 .
drwx------  5      700 root     4.0K Jul 14 10:39 ..
drwx------ 13      700 root     4.0K Jul 12 10:16 anaconda
drwx------  4      700 root     4.0K Jul 12 09:28 data
drwx------  3      700 root     4.0K Jul 12 10:38 legacy
drwx------  2      700 root      12K Jul 14 12:45 logs
drwx------  3      700 root     4.0K Jul 12 09:47 mongodb
drwxrw-rw-  4 rabbitmq rabbitmq 4.0K Jul 14 13:05 rabbitmq
```

Comment: I have the exactly same problem. Did you resolve it?

Comment: Same issue here, unable to solve it for now ...

Answer (score 0):

The solution which works for me is to disable SELINUX